# Union of sets of a partition not equal to the original set

Tags: set-partition

Is there a name for a "partition" where the union of its sets is not equal to the original set, but still disjoint?

Comment: This is just a collection of disjoint subsets. I'd be surprised if there were another name for it.

Comment: See [MSE question 2887399](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2887399) "Definition of subpartition".

Answer (score 0):

You could call it the set of blocks of a [partial equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_equivalence_relation).